# Wie liest man Nummern in Namen wie "Elisabeth II." vor?

Tags: person-names

> Wir freuen uns auf den Besuch von Königin Elisabeth II.

Wie spricht man "Königin Elisabeth II." aus? Liest man es immer als Genitiv (Elisabeth der Zweiten) vor?

Comment: Lustigerweise ist es in deinem Beispiel sogar der Dativ – aber der ist immerhin formgleich mit dem Genitiv, also kann man die Verwechslung verstehen ;)

Comment: Eine Sprachausgabe die ich ausprobiert habe (in Englisch) kannte "Queen Elizabeth the Second" für Elizabeth II, aber Zar Alexander II wurde "Tsar Alexander Eee-Eee".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wenn die Queen im Nominativ steht:

> Königin Elisabeth die Zweite besuchte Berlin.

Wenn sie selbst im Genitiv steht:

> Das ist der Hut der Königin Elisabeth der Zweiten.

Dativ:

> Dieser Hut gehört Königin Elisabeth der Zweiten.

Akkusativ:

> Heute sehen wir Königin Elisabeth die Zweite.

Answer (score 14):

Für eine Königin ist es etwas schwerer zu erkennen als für einen König, da die Flexion von Feminina weniger eindeutig ist; deswegen möchte ich Huberts Antwort dahingehend ergänzen:

> Das ist Heinrich **der Dreizehnte**. (Nominativ)
>
> München ist eine Gründung Heinrichs **des Dreizehnten**. (Genitiv)
>
> Die Untertanen erwiesen Heinrich **dem Dreizehnten** die Ehre. (Dativ)
>
> Die englische Königstochter Mathilde heiratete Heinrich **den Dreizehnten**. (Akkusativ)

Das funktioniert nicht nur für Zahlen, sondern auch für Beinamen:

> Das ist Heinrich **der Löwe**.
>
> München ist eine Gründung Heinrichs **des Löwen**.
>
> Die Untertanen erwiesen Heinrich **dem Löwen** die Ehre.
>
> Die englische Königstochter Mathilde heiratete Heinrich **den Löwen**.

Comment: Zusatzfrage zum Spaß: Was macht man denn bei König Carl XVI Gustaf (kung Carl den sextonde Gustaf)?

Comment: @MartinPeters spontan *König Carl XVI. Gustafs*. Analog zum Bürgerlichen Herr Carl Gustaf Bernadotte – der Besuch *Carl Gustafs*

Comment: @Martin Peters: Ich würde _Karl der Sechzehnte Gustav_ sagen und _der Besuch Karls des Sechzehnten Gustav_.

Comment: @chirlu Hm, Gustaf.

Comment: @Jan Zwei Möglichkeiten, nicht so klar, was richtig ist. Vielleicht gehen auch beide?

Comment: @Martin Peters: Traditionell werden Herrschernamen der jeweiligen Sprache angepaßt: Heinrich der Achte, nicht Henry der Achte; Elisabeth die Zweite, nicht Elizabeth die Zweite; Benedikt der Sechzehnte, nicht Benedictus der Sechzehnte. Das nimmt allerdings ab; so gut wie niemand nennt den britischen Thronfolger Prinz Karl. Auch Papst Franz wird in D zumeist Franziskus genannt (sein Namenspatron Franz von Assisi aber nicht), also nur halbherzig eingedeutscht.

Answer (score 4):

Die Zahl wird (wie durch den Punkt angedeutet) als Ordinalzahl gelesen und folgt im Genus dem Geschlecht der Person (*Elisabeth die Zweite*, *Wilhelm der Zweite*). Der Kasus richtet sich nach der Rolle im Satz:

> Elisabeth die Zweite besucht Deutschland.
>   Die anglikanische Kirche wurde von Heinrich dem Achten gegründet.
>   Das Denkmal erinnert an Friedrich Wilhelm den Vierten.
>   Papst Benedikt der Sechzehnte war Nachfolger Johannes Pauls des Zweiten.

Dasselbe gilt für Beinamen:

> das Grab Ludwigs des Frommen

Wenn man in historischem Zusammenhang, etwa in einer Vorlesung, von vielen unterschiedlichen Herrschern spricht, wechselt man aus Gründen der Sprachökonomie gelegentlich zur Kardinalzahl (*Wilhelm zwo*).

Comment: Diesen Wechsel zur Kardinalzahl empfinde ich als ziemlich schlechten Stil und habe das zum Glück bisher auch nur sehr selten gehört.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Schön ist es sicher nicht, aber kürzer. ;-)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, ist aber usus.

Comment: @NinaScholz: Wann, bzw. wo? Ich habe das bisher wie gesagt nur sehr selten gehört.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, da ich nur anekdotisch antworten kann, lasse ich das.

Answer (score 3):

"Elisabeth II." ist eine Kurzschreibweise für "Elisabeth die Zweite". Grammatikalisch handelt es sich dabei um eine Apposition mit enger Bindung. Unter diesen werden mehrere Kategorien unterschieden, die hinsichtlich ihrer Flektion nicht einheitlich behandelt werden. Bei Herrschernamen u.ä. (z.B. "Lucas Cranach der Ältere") stimmt die Apposition mit dem Bezugswort im Kasus überein.

Quelle: [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Satzgliedbau/Nomen/Apposition.html#Anchor-Apposition-3800)

In

> Wir freuen uns auf den Besuch von Elisabeth II.

steht *Elisabeth* im Dativ, folglich ist der Dativ von *die Zweite* zu bilden, also *der Zweiten*.

Dein Beispielsatz

> Wir freuen uns auf den Besuch von Königin Elisabeth II.

enthält streng genommen noch eine weitere Apposition, nämlich den Titel *Königin*. Wie ebenfalls [bei canoo](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Satzgliedbau/Nomen/Apposition.html#Anchor-Apposition-35882) erklärt wird, wird dabei der Name ("Elisabeth"), aber nicht der Titel ("Königin") flektiert. Das ist theoretisch wichtig, wenn jemand den Satz mit Genitiv statt Dativ formuliert:

> Wir freuen uns auf den Besuch Königin Elisabeth**s** II.

Dann ist *Elisabeths* ein Genitiv, folglich ist der Genitiv von *die Zweite* zu bilden. Praktisch landest Du damit aber wieder bei *der Zweiten*.

Comment: Und wieder ist Elisabeth ein schlechtes Beispiel, weil der Genitiv von *Königin* *Königin* ist. Mit Königen funktioniert das wiederum: »Der Besuch *König Ludwigs des Zweiten* versetzte Hintertupflfing in helle Aufregung.«

Comment: Wobei (wie Canoo auch sagt) es genau umgekehrt ist, wenn man von _der_ Königin spricht, denn dann ist es kein Titel mehr, sondern der Hauptbegriff (und der Name ist die Apposition dazu): _den Besuch der Königin Elisabeth der Zweiten_ (bzw. _den Besuch des Königs Ludwig des Zweiten_)